# Scala: Expand Macros at Runtime

Tags: scala, macros, runtime, abstract-syntax-tree

How can the AST be obtained for scala code after the macros have been expanded at runtime?

```
  // obtain toolbox
  val tb = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
  // generate the AST
  val tree = tb.parse(<...source code using one or more macros...>)
  // let's look at the code
  println(show(tree))
  // let's see what the AST looks like
  println(showRaw(tree))
  // expand macros!
  xTreem = ?????
  // now let's look at the code and AST
  println(show(xTreem))
  println(showRaw(xTreem))
  // compile and...
  val f = tb.compile(xTreem)
  // ... execute
  f()
```

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds pretty much like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you describe what you are really trying to achieve? Macros were not designed to be expanded at run-time at all (although you can do that, macros are designed to be expanded at compile time). I think it makes sense to describe your high-level problem.

Comment: I've recently started learning about Scala.  I'm not using it for any project at the moment.  I'm just playing around with some examples here and there.  My interest right now is in macros and how they work.  I'm curious to see how the AST is modified by them.

Comment: Sledge, if what you are really interested in is just macro in general, you should probably start with this [introduction article](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html). Among other things it provides some suggestions on how to trace (see "Inspecting generated code" section) and even debug macro (IMHO you should not do it unless you really must).

Comment: That's actually where I started, and it's very useful.  I found the compiler option `-Ymacro-debug-lite` there, and prints the tree for the macro being expanded at the time.  However, it doesn't give the tree for the entire code post expansion.  Using the toolbox and printing out the entire tree before expansion and comparing it to the compiler output can get me there, but I was hoping for something a bit less painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around, I have not found a way to get the post-macro-expanded AST at runtime using the current experimental reflect and compiler API docs, but I can use the compiler option `-Ymacro-debug-lite` to print out each macro as it gets expanded at compile time.  Also, there's scalamacros.org and scalameta.org which propose the next gen of AST inspection/manipulation and macros.